# Amazon Rds m4 VS m3, which is better

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I looked here: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

It's seems like amazon rds M4 Is better and cheaper then M3, 
It's doesnt makes sense to me.

Why would anyone want to use M3

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. M4 is the latest generation server type on AWS. You would want to use M4 instead of M3 for new servers you are creating.

Answer (score 8):

The M3s are the previous generation, and as you correctly note are slower and more expensive, therefore if you were starting up a new RDS instance the obvious choice would be M4. However M4s are not available in all regions yet (South America being the one remaining region offering only M3s.)

(It also makes sense to continue displaying pricing for users still running M3 instances.)

Comment: As an update to the above, M4 class instances became available in all AWS regions as of September 2016: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/introducing-new-m4-instance-size-m4-16xlarge-and-new-region-availability-of-m4-instances/

The previous rationale still applies for users who may have already running instances of M3 class or have reserved capacity.

Answer (score 1):

M4 have no local instance storage, so you have to pay (in terms of delay) for network traffic for all disk writes, which slows up things that could be much faster with instance store, such as paging file, SQL Server temp databases, etc.

Comment: So Im using M3 and I have a 35 GB disk because default disk size not large enough, will M4 disk access be slower or same as this ?